# How do I conclude that $z \mapsto \frac 1 {(z-a)^2}$ has an antiderivative in $\mathbb C \setminus \{a\}$ for $a \in \mathbb C$ ?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

How do I conclude that $z \mapsto \frac 1 {(z-a)^2}$ has an anti-derivative in $\mathbb C \setminus \{a\}$ for $a \in \mathbb C$ ?

I see that the function is certainly holomorphic in the above region, but how do I determine that an anti-derivative exist ?

I've tried to conclude that every closed path integral in $0$ without luck.

Also, does  $z \mapsto \frac 1 {z-a}$ has an anti-derivative ?

Comment: One can always just exhibit an explicit antiderivative. For the second question, you could apply the approach you mentioned and look for a path $\gamma$ such that the integral $\int_{\gamma} \frac{dz}{z - a}$ is nonzero.

Comment: how would that look ?

Comment: What is the antiderivative of the real function $x \mapsto \frac{1}{(x - a)^2}$?

Comment: But I can't use the logarithm. The textbook has not stated it yet.

Comment: The antiderivative of that function is not logarithmic.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I see it is $$\frac {-1} {z-a}$$ -- Thanks !